# Canon EOS T5 video noisy

Tags: dslr, canon, noise-reduction, noise

When I film at least at 3200 ISO I have so much noise in my video that the video is unwatchable. I tried the denoiser in Adobe Premiere pro but it removes all the details and it doesn't remove colour noise, is there any free plugin to remove colour noise?
[image]

Comment: Add more light.

Comment: My phose is less noisy in the same situation